# Lato font missing letters in IE and Firefox

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, fonts, google-font-api

WTF is going on with Lato Google Hosted (not sure about fontface) Font??? On IE 8, the font looks scrambled with letters missing and word spaces missing and I hear that it's the same on earlier (not so earlier) versions of firefox!

What's the point of a font / or a hosted a font when you can't read it on many browsers!!
Lato went from hero to zero for me unless someone has a fix for it?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle atleast so we can confirm?

Comment: It's happening to me too. Lato being used here: http://chrisbenard.net/contact/ - It's messed up in Firefox and IE only.

Comment: @Brunis Fiddle to confirm: http://jsfiddle.net/cbenard/p4oao7tr/

Comment: Same problem here. IE 9 not working too

Comment: You need to state exactly where the problem can be observed (which letters where are wrong how) and to provide a testable case in the question itself; a link is not enough (though better than nothing).

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I'm not OP. OP doesn't even have a real username so I doubt this is going to get any high quality updates from OP. I've linked to a fiddle above though, and I've submitted an edit to OP's question that hasn't been approved yet with a thorough example (code and output screenshot). Waiting on it to be approved since I don't have 2k rep.

Comment: See issue https://code.google.com/p/googlefontdirectory/issues/detail?id=331

Comment: My [suggested edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5595359) was rejected as "would change too much" even though everyone asked for an example. @pppeater I replied to the Google tracker with the example.

Comment: Within the last hour or two I independently have noticed our Google-hosted Lato font is screwed up on Windows.

Comment: @ChrisBenard, adding a complete example is indeed too big an edit. An edit should improve the wording or format of a question, not provide a testable case on behalf of the OP. I think this question should simply be closed unless the OP can provide a testable case. Anyone who has an actual demonstration of a problem with Lato can post it as a new question.

Comment: To see what I mean, go to http://www.apartmint.co.za/ ... and test it on ie8 and firefox (I cannot believe the problem lies on firefox too? What version though?)

Comment: This page https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Lato mentions an August 2014 update and suggests adding more subsets, however the recommended snippet did not fix the problem for me for basic roman characters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lato 2.0 was released on Google Fonts today, however it has a problem:

> Adam Twardoch, font developer, says, "In Lato 1, I used FontLab Studio to autohint the two thinnest weights and ttfautohint for the rest. In Lato 2, I used ttfautohint for all. This seems to not have been a good idea. I'll see what I can do about it very soon."
>
> Meanwhile, the Google Fonts API will rollback the update today.

https://code.google.com/p/googlefontdirectory/issues/detail?id=331

Comment: I'm happy to see that the developer has picked up on the problem and is addressing it :) I see the font is now rendering properly on IE8 which I assume is working on earlier versions of firefox

Comment: Although the Lato font is now working in IE8, it's still not rendering properly in an earlier version of firefox (I need to find out what version firefox my friend is using - once I do, I'll post FYI)

Comment: Make sure your friend does a hard cache refresh. As far as I can tell they just did a rollback.

Answer (score 2):

The font was updated today, but the hinting regressed, so the update is being rolled back.