# Why does the IE9 render "Lato" webfont not correctly?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, webfonts, typography

I'm working on a prototype for a website and when i take a look at the site on IE9 some characters are missing.

I got the fonts from lato-fonts[dot]com and embeded them via @import in my main CSS-file at the beginning.

When i inspect the missing characters with the F12-Tool, it shows me the complete word, but not in the output.

[image]

It should be like "STARTSEITE | IHR KONTO | KASSE | ANMELDEN" (w/o the lines)

My code in the css-file looks like this:

```
@import url(../fonts/Lato/Lato-Bold.css);
@import url(../fonts/Lato/Lato-BoldItalic.css);
@import url(../fonts/Lato/Lato-Thin.css);
@import url(../fonts/Lato/Lato-ThinItalic.css);
@import url(../fonts/Lato/Lato-Medium.css);
@import url(../fonts/Lato/Lato-MediumItalic.css);
@import url(../fonts/Lato/Lato-Italic.css);
@import url(../fonts/Lato/Lato-Regular.css);
@import url(../fonts/Lato/Lato-Hairline.css);
@import url(../fonts/Lato/Lato-HairlineItalic.css);
@import url(../fonts/Lato/Lato-Light.css);
@import url(../fonts/Lato/Lato-LightItalic.css);


/* MAIN <<<<<<>>>>> TYPO */
.no-gutter > [class*='col-'] {
    padding-right:0;
    padding-left:0;
}
body {
    font-family:"Lato",Verdana,sans-serif;
    color:rgba(0,0,0,.9);

}
```

Is there maybe anyone who had the same problem and could help me out?

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25434089/lato-font-missing-letters-in-ie-and-firefox