# Lato font broken in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, fonts

I have developped a website using Lato Google Font. Everything works fine with Chrome but when I use Firefox, the font is broken and I get a Times New Roman font instead.

The weird thing is that when I open https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Lato I do get Lato Font. So my guess is that there is something wrong with my code.

The website is http://www.okaprix.com/
This is the CSS code i wrote to use Lato Font :

```
/* latin-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Lato';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Lato Regular'), local('Lato-Regular'), url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/lato/v11/UyBMtLsHKBKXelqf4x7VRQ.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+1E00-1EFF, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Lato';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Lato Regular'), local('Lato-Regular'), url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/lato/v11/1YwB1sO8YE1Lyjf12WNiUA.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215, U+E0FF, U+EFFD, U+F000;
}
body {
font-family : Lato;
margin : 0 auto;
height : 100%;
font-size: 16px;
min-width:1066px;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lato font missing letters in IE and Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25434089/lato-font-missing-letters-in-ie-and-firefox)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how you implement a Google Fonts. Use the following tag in the `head` of your page:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Then just simply specify Lato in the stylesheet.

Comment: If you open that link (http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato) you'll find that's just a CSS file with the code I wrote.

Comment: I think you'll find the problem is that you can't call the .woff files directly from your site - you have to load Google's style sheet instead.

Comment: Ok. That seems to be the problem. Thanks !